# C# Как разбить строку

Tags: c#, .net

В единственной строке входного файла INPUT.TXT записана строка(без пробелов и чего либо еще) длиной от 1 до 50.
Как пример входного файла: CBABCACCC;
Подскажите как разбить эту строку в массив строк {"C","B","A",...}
Или просто считать эту строку как массив без пробелов, где первая буква будет = первому елементу сторокового массива.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ничего не понял. По какому принципу `CBABCACCC` разбивается в `{"C","B","A",...}`?

Comment: string.ToCharArray() или что-то такое

Comment: @Philippe спасибо огромное)

Comment: А нужно ли разбивать? Простое обращение к i-му символу не подходит?

Answer (score 0):

```
    string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"INPUT.TXT");

    List<string> mas = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        mas.Add(s[i].ToString());
    }

    string[] result = mas.ToArray();
```